# What kind of preprocessing does Mathematica do when I use EdgeDetect on an image?

Tags: image-processing, implementation-details

I am doing my own implementation of Canny and Sobel in another language (not in *Mathematica*). I was testing the `EdgeDetect` method (Sobel and Canny), and my own, and I am getting different results.

What kind of preprocessing does `EdgeDetect` do to the image before detecting the edges, and what kind of threshold does it use?

Comment: While I don't know much about these methods, looking at what Mathematica and MATLAB do differently: it seems thresholding is not done the same way.  See under Details in the EdgeDetect docs.

Answer (score 3):

If you drill down the documents' *details and options* you may find some useful information. Here is my take:

EdgeDetect has 2 main parameters pixel range *r* and *t* for threshold. The document says the *r*'s default value is 2. For threshold *t* uses hysteresis thresholding with a global threshold t. For additional forms of the threshold parameter, see the reference page for MorphologicalBinarize is pointed in the document. MorphologicalBinarize automatically choosing a suitable value for the lower threshold. FindThreshold uses default "Cluster" method which is cluster variance maximization (Otsu's algorithm).

In addition the method may contain StraightEdges; Method->{"method","StraightEdges"->s}. The default behavior is equivalent to "StraightEdges"->0. A setting "StraightEdges"->1 selects only the longest and strongest lines.